# Is there a way to know if the chat is active?

Tags: javascript, liveagent, chat

I'm designing the front-end of the live agent chat. In it is a button with the status. Based on the documentation, I read that it executes its own script which enables or disables the `chat();` function.

Can I make a `<span>` text dynamic based on the chat status (Online / Offline)? How would I retrieve that value?

Comment: What do you mean chat active? Do you want to know if there is any agent available to chat with customer? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce provides a method called `addButtonEventHandler` to handle such scenarios. Once you implement the method you can do JavaScript actions based on the different status like `BUTTON_AVAILABLE` or `BUTTON_UNAVAILABLE` in the Callback function. Please find the below example. I have used the callback function `btnEventHandler` to trigger the action based on the button status. From this method, you can make a span dynamic by changing the text based on the status of the Button. Hope it makes sense!

Modified LiveAgent JavaScript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!window._laq) {
        window._laq = [];
    }
    window._laq.push(function(){
        liveagent.showWhenOnline('5737F000000PCZJ', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_5737F000000PCZJ'));
        liveagent.showWhenOffline('5737F000000PCZJ', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_5737F000000PCZJ'));
    });
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function btnEventHandler(e){
        if(e == liveagent.BUTTON_EVENT.BUTTON_AVAILABLE){
            document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = "AGENT AVAILABLE";
        }else if(e == liveagent.BUTTON_EVENT.BUTTON_UNAVAILABLE){
            document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = "AGENT NOT AVAILABLE";
        }
    }
    liveagent.addButtonEventHandler('5737F000000PCZJ', btnEventHandler);        
    liveagent.init('https://d.la1-c1-ukb.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '5727F000000PDKO', '00D7F000000pzKU');
    liveagent.setChatWindowHeight(400);
    liveagent.setChatWindowWidth(350);
</script>
```

Salesforce documentation about `addButtonEventHandler`.

**addButtonEventHandler**

Use the addButtonEventHandler method to define an automated invitation’s behavior when certain events occur.

**Usage**
Defines the behavior for an invitation when the following events occur:

- The criteria are met for the invitation to appear on-screen.
- The criteria are not met for the invitation to appear on-screen.
- A customer accepts an invitation to chat.
- A customer rejects an invitation to chat.

The event “the criteria are not met for the invitation to appear on the screen” occurs when a chat can’t reach an agent using the configured chat button or automated invitation. The event occurs when:

- No agents are online.
- No agents assigned to the skills associated with the button are
  online.
- Online agents have the status Away.
- Online agents are at capacity (set with Live Agent Configurations, or
  Presence Configurations with Omni-Channel).
- Online agents are using Omni-Channel and are only available for other
  service channels.

Available in API versions 28.0 and later.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_automated_chat_invitations_API_addButtonEventHandler.htm

Comment: If my answer to the current question helped, please mark it as accepted.